# While retrieving the bucket name from aws lambda event I am getting this error. ( "errorMessage": "'Records'" "errorType": "KeyError")

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

The command I'm trying to run is

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    
    #retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = event['query']['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
```

The result:

```json
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

The error:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
END RequestId: 29150087-77bd-49db-a88b-61eb8a1645fd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the output of your `print` statement, it is clear that the event does not have a property called `Records`.

```json
{
    'key1': 'value1', 
    'key2': 'value2', 
    'key3': 'value3'
}
```

So when you run `event['Records']` it does not work. Because the JSON above does not have a property with name `Records`.

This would work if you have the following JSON:

```json
{
    'Records': [],
    'key1': 'value1', 
    'key2': 'value2', 
    'key3': 'value3'
}
```

If that would be the JSON, then `events['Records']` would return `[]`.

Based on the JSON of your event, I can tell that you are using the AWS Consoles "Test" features default event JSON.

You need to provide the proper JSON in the AWS console for AWS S3 Events.

It is documented here: [Event message structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html)

The JSON should look like this:

```json
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.2",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
         "eventTime":"The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, when Amazon S3 finished processing the request",
         "eventName":"event-type",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-user-who-caused-the-event"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"ip-address-where-request-came-from"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"Amazon S3 generated request ID",
            "x-amz-id-2":"Amazon S3 host that processed the request"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-bucket-owner"
               },
               "arn":"bucket-ARN"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
               "size":"object-size",
               "eTag":"object eTag",
               "versionId":"object version if bucket is versioning-enabled, otherwise null",
               "sequencer": "a string representation of a hexadecimal value used to determine event sequence, only used with PUTs and DELETEs"
            }
         },
         "glacierEventData": {
            "restoreEventData": {
               "lifecycleRestorationExpiryTime": "The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, of Restore Expiry",
               "lifecycleRestoreStorageClass": "Source storage class for restore"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: @SakethNaidu yeah. I just understood what your "result" is supposed to be. I'll update.

Comment: But how do I make it work so that it doesn't take "Test" environment and takes the jsons of the events triggered ??

Comment: @SakethNaidu You need to configure your S3 bucket to send an event to your Lambda. There is detailed documentation about it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html

Comment: configured my s3 to send an event to the required lambda. Followed all the steps mentioned. BUt no luck  :(